# IE 11 cookies in Developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools, ie11-developer-tools

Is there an equivalent to Chrome's cookie view in IE 11 ?

Chrome's cookie viewer: Resources->Cookies.
Closest IE11 has is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941029/how-do-i-view-cookies-in-internet-explorer-11-using-developer-tools) : Network -> Go to url -> click on details - > Cookies.

[IE 11 Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11) has this under removed features: "Ability to view all cookies at once via Developer Tools".

Comment: Hi @cbono, I already mentioned existing IE 11 cookie viewer in the question. Added your link to the question. I was checking if there is a cookie viewer for site instead of going to network and then to url to show all cookies. Anyway thanks for replying.

Comment: see my answer in this url :-
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839967/anyone-know-of-a-utility-for-viewing-editing-cookies-on-ie-8/44946976#44946976

Comment: @Nash This is still a duplicate. I understand that you didn't get the answer you want, but that does not make this question a different one. The OP of that question, `KingOfHypocrites`, asked for the same thing you are asking for.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There currently is not a dedicated Cookie viewer in the IE11 F12 Developer tools.

There are two possible workarounds:

1. Inspecting cookies within the "Detailed view" in the Network tab
2. Running 'document.cookie' in the Javascript console

Comment: If you use the Network tab, remember to enable network capturing first.

Comment: I guess this didn't match with there GUI

Comment: The `Detailed View` only shows cookies name and its value. no other filed is shown. I am interested in getting cookies expiry date. How can I get this?

Comment: `Running 'document.cookie'` will not work if the cookie is marked as HTTPOnly

Answer (score 9):

You can use console of IE to edit any value of cookie

Now first hit below commond

```
document.cookie
```

It will return you some key values. Now use below command to edit or create new key values

```
document.cookie="YOURKEY=YOURVALUE"
```

[image]

Hope it will help you :)

Note :- It will works, if the cookie is not marked as HTTPOnly

Comment: Did you want to say "it will work only, if the cookie is NOT marked as HTTPOnly"?

HttpOnly flag means cookie isn't accessible from script

Answer (score 0):

As Eric says it, there's not way to do this in IE11.

I have been troubling with this for some time, but I finally had to see it as a lost course, and just navigate to the files manually.

But where are the files? That depends on a lot of things, I have found them these places on different machines:

### In the the Internet Explorer cache.

This can be done via "run" (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and then typing in `shell:cache` or by navigating to it through the internet options in IE11 ([AskLeo has a fine guide to this](https://askleo.com/how-do-i-view-cookies-in-ie-11/), I'm not affiliated in any way).

> - Click on the gear icon, then Internet options.
> - In the General tab, underneath “Browsing history”, click on Settings.
> - In the resulting “Website Data” dialog, click on View files.
> - This will open the folder we’re interested in: your Internet Explorer cache.

Make a search for "cookie" to see the cookies only

### In the Cookies folder

Sometimes you can also find the cookies here (Win 7 & 8)

> %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
>
> %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low

Or here (Win 10)

> shell:cookies
>
> shell:cookies\low
>
> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
>
> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies\Low