# how to watch Internet Explorer local cookies

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, session-cookies, mozilla, ie11-developer-tools

I want to check whether my session cookies are secure or not in IE11. I am able to check it in chrome and Mozilla but unable to find anything in IE11.

```
chrome--> DevTools>Application>Storage>Cookies
Mozilla--> DevTools>Storage>Cookies
Edge--> DevTools>Debugger>Cookies
```

**Note: I don't want to check cookie request header inside network tab in developer tools**
thanks

Edit: I think I found the answer.
[IE 11 cookies in Developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006062/ie-11-cookies-in-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Microsoft has removed cookie view feature from IE11.

[IE 11 cookies in Developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006062/ie-11-cookies-in-developer-tools)